# eevee principled volume shape is off

Tags: eevee-render-engine, volumetrics

I was tring to use principled volume to make dust that flow along the ground surface which is displaced to a certain amount. My first try is to distort the volume box mesh by shrinkwrap a plane to the ground mesh then solidify it. But it seems eevee volume is only work with the bounding box instead of actual mesh of the object.

Then I take another try that use raycast in the gn node to sample the ground shape to get a z shift to mix with my dust noise texture. So that the noise will be curved to control the density of the volume. But still the volume is only shown my noise part of the density, ignoring the attibute I transfered from gn node(named “12” in this case).
[image: the density texture is correct]

[image: but the actual volume is wrong]

Can someone let me know is this just a engine issue or am I doing something wrong.

Comment: _Eevee_ is not capable of using the shape of an object for volumes, it will always use the complete bounding box. You need _Cycles_ for that.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann thank you Gordon! But I've already figured it out as I said in the first half of my question. But what about the second half of my question? It is not about the bounding box anymore. I used a curved noise to control the shape but it is still not working properly.

Comment: Yes, you figured it out, but you wrote "it seems" - sometimes things are not what they seem, especially newbies might not know if it is as it seems or if they are doing something wrong. So I just wanted to clarify what you discovered is definitely the case here. For the second part, well I didn't have time to decode your node setup and have no answer for this - that's why I just wrote a comment on volume in _Eevee_ and did not post a full-fledged answer in the answer section.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Thank you for the clarification! It dose help to build my knowledge.